# Outlook.MailItem.DownloadState What it is and what it is used for?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

I have seen the property Outlook.MailItem.DownloadState which is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.downloadstate).
Anyway I am not able to understand what is it and what is it used for. Some can explain me that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To decrease the capacity of the local storage and save the bandwidth users may not download large emails getting only a small subset of data (metadata) which contains the headers describing the email.

There are possible states for the [MailItem.DownloadState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldownloadstate) property:

- The `olHeaderOnly` means only the header has been downloaded.
- The `olFullItem` value means the full item has been downloaded.

If the message was not fully downloaded in Outlook you can set the [MailItem.MarkForDownload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.markfordownload) property. It returns or sets an `OlRemoteStatus` constant that determines the status of an item once it is received by a remote user.

```
if(obj.DownloadState == olHeaderOnly)
{ 
   'Mark the item to be downloaded
    obj.MarkForDownload = olMarkedForDownload;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Outlook has header-only mode when it downloads headers first and full item (body and attachment) only when the message is selected - see https://www.officetooltips.com/outlook_2016/tips/how_to_set_outlook_to_download_only_e-mail_headers.html